# Neither JWPlayer nor FlowPlayer will play a .swf video properly

Tags: javascript, flash, video, jwplayer, flowplayer

I am experiencing a very weird issue with both jquery2flash players,

this is how i am callin flowplayer:

```
flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.8.swf",{
                clip:  {
                  autoPlay: false
              }
});
```

this is how i am calling jwplayer:

```
jwplayer("player1").setup({
            skin: "http://content.longtailvideo.com/skins/glow/glow.zip",
            stretching: "fill",
            flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
            image: "http://s1-www.ltvimg.com/v3_5_5/images/jw-player/lWMJeVvV-720.jpg",
            width: 720,
            height:406,
            levels: [
                        {file: "http://d2p65vgzoeytng.cloudfront.net/comun/0720/video/sol_gavilanes.swf"},
                        {file: "http://d2p65vgzoeytng.cloudfront.net/comun/0720/video/sol_gavilanes.swf"}
                    ]
});
```

The problem is that in both even if you click on the play button, the video will start but the play icon won't hide

Also, in flowplayer the player will add an extra instance of the video (or at least the sound) each time you click the play button.

I am really not sure why this won't work as expected, what am i missing here?

It can be tested here: http://toniweb.us/m/flash/

It can be tweaked here: http://jsfiddle.net/S3RMq/1/

-EDIT-
Also, the volume controls won't work

-EDIT- with .flv neither work http://jsfiddle.net/S3RMq/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your .swf file. Try it with http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv 
I recommend you to use .mp4 format

http://flowplayer.org/forum/2/14874

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your .swf file. Try it with http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv 
I recommend you to use .mp4 format